# Is there a way to vectorize this loop

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize this code to eliminate the for loop:

```
import numpy as np
Z = np.concatenate((X, labels[:,None]), axis=1)
centroids = np.empty([len(unique(labels))-1,2])
for i in unique(labels[labels>-1]):
    centroids[i,:]=Z[Z[:,-1]==i][:,:-1].mean(0)
centroids
```

This code produces pseudo centroids from the [DBSCAN scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#example-cluster-plot-dbscan-py), in case you want to play with it to find a vectorized form, i.e. `X` and `labels` are defined in the example.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bincount()` three times:

```
count = np.bincount(labels)
x = np.bincount(labels, X[:, 0])
y = np.bincount(labels, X[:, 1])

centroids = np.c_[x, y] / count[:, None]
print centroids
```

But if you can use pandas, this is very simple:

```
Z = np.concatenate((X, labels[:,None]), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=("x", "y", "label"))
df[df['label']>-1].groupby("label").mean()
```

Comment: Great answer HYRY, thanks for your help!  The first numpy version doesn't quite work since there is a negative value in labels for the outliers, which is why I have 'labels[labels>-1]'.  The pandas version works great and I can eliminate the negative index via the minor edit that I included above.  If you have a fix for this issue in the numpy solution, I would enjoy seeing it.  Thanks again!